# Como utilizar async/await em métodos que retornam void?

Tags: c#, winforms, thread, async, assincronismo

Estou com um problema em minha aplicação, onde devido ao grande volume de processamento, o meu `Form` trava. Durante minhas pesquisas descobri que um método `async` resolve isso, porem as funções executadas no meu botão "executar" retornam void, desta forma não posso usar o `await` pois não sei quando a execução da função vai acabar(pois ela não retorna uma task).

Ah algum jeito de usar Thread ou Task neste cenário?
Destravando o form e dividindo o processamento?

EDIT APÓS SUGESTÕES:

Meu `for` ficou desta forma após as sugestões:

```
for (i = iTemp; i < evolucoes; i++)
        {
            iTemp++;

            lbEvolucoes.Text = i.ToString();
            lbEvolucoes.Refresh();

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
              {
                  pop = AG.executeGA(pop);
              });


            // pop = AG.executeGA(pop);

            //Limpar o grafico
            zedMedia.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear();
            zedMedia.GraphPane.GraphObjList.Clear();

            double mediaPop = pop.getMediaPop();
            mediaPopulacao.Add(i, mediaPop);

            double bestFitness = pop.getBest().getFitness();

            #region Começo do dois opt

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>                 
            {

                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Utils.TwoOpt(pop.getBest());
                    }));
            });

            #endregion

            lbMenorDistancia.Text = bestFitness.ToString();
            lbMenorDistancia.Refresh();

            LineItem media = paneMedia.AddCurve("Média", mediaPopulacao, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);

            //Print linhas a cada 6 evolucoes
            if (i % 6 == 0 && bestFitness < bestAux)
            {
                bestAux = bestFitness;
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                plotLines(pop, Color.Blue);
                plotPoints();
            }

            zedMedia.AxisChange();
            zedMedia.Invalidate();
            zedMedia.Refresh();
        }
```

Ficou desta forma, está legal?

Comment: Você não está conseguindo retornar um `async void`? Outra solução também é usar o `Task.Factory`

Comment: Então não adianta retornar um void , pq eu teria que dizer para meu form ficar funcionando enquanto a função nao acaba de processar , isso eu faria com o await, porem com retorno void nao é possível chamar o Await, pois a função precisa retornar um Task dizendo que acabou, Factory tmb nao deu :/

Comment: Tornar o método chamador `async` e colocar `await` antes da chamado a um método não faz que o código do método chamado seja executado de forma assíncrona. Uma forma possível é usar `Task.Factory.StartNew(metodo())` para o chamar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um método que retorna `void` também pode ser assíncrono, consequentemente, você também pode utilizar o `await` dentro dele.

Para deixa-lo assíncrono, inclua o prefixo `async` no seu cabeçalho, veja um exemplo:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Uma forma de não fazer ele roda-lo em "top-level"(protegido de exceções não observadas), é utilizar o `Task.Factory`, veja:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //métodos aqui
    });
}
```

Comment: Pelo que percebi da pergunta aquele `async` em `StartNew(async () => ` está a mais.

Comment: Se você não dizer que a Action é async, você não vai conseguir usar o await dentro dela @ramaral

Comment: Sim, mas para isso o método, a chamar dentro do StartNew, tem de retornar uma Task. O AP diz que retorna `void`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo toque, vou editar. @ramaral

Comment: Francisco, obrigado pela ajuda, conforme visto acima, postei o codigo de como meu for ficou, o que achou?

Comment: @GuilhermePrado recomendo que coloque todo o código dentro da `Task` criada com a factory, inclusive o laço `for`.

Comment: @GuilhermePrado Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, por favor marque-a como correta! =)

Comment: @Francisco Esta certo eu criar uma lista de task para aumentar o processamento da função?

Comment: @GuilhermePrado Se for tudo thread-safe, sim. Mas lembre-se que para esperar a execução você deve utilizar o await. Da uma olhada no [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Basta você declarar seu método como `async` e colocar o tipo de retorno `Task`, que seria um `void` multithread.

Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

public async Task ExecutarMetodoAsync()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Exemplo
        await httpClient.PostAsync("", null);
    }
}
```

Se você precisar retornar algum valor você define o tipo de retorno da `Task`, exemplo abaixo:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

public async Task<string> ExecutarMetodoAsync()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        // Exemplo
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync("");
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, o que achou?